# How to compare two tuple in list?

Tags: haskell

I have list of tuples like this:

```
[(0.0,0.0),(1.0,0.0),(2.0,0.0),(3.0,0.0),(3.0,0.0),(3.0,0.0),(4.0,0.0),(4.0,0.0)]
```

where first element is the X-coordinate and second the Y-coordinate and I now want to write function that will return :

```
[(0.0,0.0),(1.0,0.0),(2.0,0.0),(3.0,0.0),(3.0,1.0),(3.0,2.0),(4.0,0.0),(4.0,1.0)]
```

It takes first element from first tuple and first from second tuple and if they are not equal, Y is unchanged but if they are equal we add one to Y.

if someone has an idea how to write in Haskell?

Comment: Sounds like you might benefit from functions like `groupBy` and co in `Data.List`.  Take a look at that module to see if there's anything that gives you an idea of how to solve this.

Comment: I was thinking about lambda and map but I have no idea how to combine it with checking tuples in list

Comment: Try writing small functions which handle each part of your algorithm. For example, write a function which takes two tuples and increment the second element if and only if the first element is the same.

Comment: so what's the result of this? What's the type of the result?  It's a bit unclear from your description.  Do you know how to pattern match on tuples?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want instead to turn [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4] into [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 0), (4, 1)]? Doubles aren't that great for equality checking after you've done any arithmetic on them, and you don't seem to need the initial y. If I'm right, you want `group`, `concatMap`, `zip` and `[0..]`. You can find the first three on hoogle/hayoo, which you can find on google.

Answer (score -1):

Not tested, but something like this will do:

```
foo :: [(Float, Float)] -> [(Float, Float)]
foo []  = []
foo [x] = [x]
foo ((xx, xy):(yx, yy):xs) = (xx, xy): theTuple : (foo ((yx, yy):xs))
    where
        theTuple = if xx == yx then (yx, yy) else (yx, yy+1)
```